# How to investigate the behavior of C in Soft Margin Linear Support Vector Machine?

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

I know what is C and what is Soft Margin Linear SVM. But, couldn't find any way to solution the above 3 questions. Can you please, explain and give the proper answer.

I think, I should use the decision boundary equation W.x + b = 0. But, can't what should I plot for w,x and b? And how can I find the C from the given data points and compare the results?

Comment: Your work, thoughts something? I suggest you provide some of this if you want feedback.

Comment: I have updated the query. Actually, I can not find which equation should I use to plot the datasets and how can I find the C and then compare?